# Adobe Illustrator: Variable font size along a path

Tags: adobe-illustrator

all.

So I have a curving path in Illustrator and I've put some text on it using the "Type on Path" tool. I want to make the font size of that text gradually increase towards the middle and then gradually decrease again towards the end.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE!!! Manually changing the size of characters is probably what is needed. If you can link to an example, there may be other options. But Type on a Path has some restrictions.

Comment: Good question i think it should be possible in corel draw. But i don't see why not in Illustrator or photoshop. However, it is common to find the most basic features missing somehow.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like a job for the almighty **Envelope Distort**. Bonus - you don't have to expand the text, so you can still edit the text as a live "Type on a path" object.

The easy option is to use one of the options from `Object > Envelope Distort > Make with Warp` menu.

---

If you want more precise control (here's an example where we really mangle the text)...

1: `Object > Envelope Distort > Make with Mesh`, choose a number of rows/columns that suits the shape

[image]

2: Adjust the points to taste with the direct selection (`A`) tool - make sure the top left 'Envelope' button is set to 'Edit envelope' on the left.

[image]

3: To edit the text while keeping the effect, change the top button to Edit Contents (the star on the right)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There is one method I have tried.

1. Type a line of text
2. Create outlines
3. Distort it in the way you like
4. Expand it and make art brush
5. Apply brush on the curve

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with  Effect > Warp > Bulge
It's not as almighty Envelope Distort but you can control the values quite nice.

Dont mind the german labels

[image]

Comment: Nice quick method if it's a reasonably straight path. You can also get a 'best of both' using `Object > Envelope distort > Make with warp`, then choosing `Bulge`: it gives you a bulge effect like this with the same controls, and also then lets  modify every point to get it to follow a text path better. ("Wulst" is a brilliant sounding word btw)